# React js Navigation through table rows

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { Dropdown, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem, Progress } from 'reactstrap';

class Notifications extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
            data:[
                {title:"Nikko Laus1" , text:"abcd" , type:"Big text" },
                {title:"Sam Collins", text:"" ,type:"Inbox style"},
                {title:"Sam ", text:"" ,type:"Image style"}   
            ]
        };
  }

  render() {
    let rows = this.state.data.map(person =>
        {
            return <TableRow key={person.id} data={person}/>
        });
    return (<div><div>
          <div className="animated fadeIn">
           <div className="px-2 mb-1">
                <Link to={'/Components/BasicNotification'} style= {{ width:20 + '%' }} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">Add Notification</Link>

                  </div>

            <br /><div className="card" style={{ width: 57 + '%' }}>
              <div className="card-header">
                 Manage Notifications
              </div>
              <div className="card-block">
               

      <table  className="table table-hover table-outline mb-0 hidden-sm-down">
        
                <tbody>
                {this.props.type.Bigtext ? <Link to={'/Components/BigText'} className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" />:
                this.props.type.ImageStyle ? <Link to={'/Components/ImageStyle'} className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" />:
                <Link to={'/Components/InboxStyle'}   className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" />}
                 {rows}</tbody>
            </table></div>

               
<br />

            </div>
          </div><div className="px-2 mb-1"><Link to={'/components/tabs'} style={{ width:20 + '%' }} className="px-1 nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">Filter Notifications</Link>
</div>
</div></div>
      
      
        
      
    )
  }
}

class TableRow extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }

    render()
    {
        return (<tr>
                    <td className="text-center">{this.props.data.title}<br />
                    {this.props.data.text}<br /></td></tr>
      
            );
    }
}


export default Notifications;
```

I want to give condition and if else condition and using that condition I want to open an particular page as seen in the code snippet.
But when I run no output comes at all.
I just wanted to do like on the basis of notification type relevant page is to be opened on clicking that table row

Comment: Can you make your question clear? Unable to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: as you can see I the code I passed an array in which type is there having 3 things as inbox style, image style and big text
I'm showing table relevant to that array. what I want right now is I want to open the relevant pages of these styles on clicking a  table row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `this.context.router.push` to dynamically change the route `onClick` of the table row. See the below snippet.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { Dropdown, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem, Progress } from 'reactstrap';

class Notifications extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
            data:[
                {title:"Nikko Laus1" , text:"abcd" , type:"Big text" },
                {title:"Sam Collins", text:"" ,type:"Inbox style"},
                {title:"Sam ", text:"" ,type:"Image style"}   
            ]
        };
  }
  static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
  }
  handleClick = (index) => {

      if(this.state.data[index].type === "Big text") {
          this.context.router.push('/Components/BigText');
      } else if(this.state.data[index].type === "Image style") {
          this.context.router.push('/Components/ImageStyle');
      } else {
          this.context.router.push('/Components/InboxStyle');
      }

  }
  render() {
    let rows = this.state.data.map((person, index) =>
        {
            return <TableRow key={person.id} data={person} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, index)}/>
        });
    return (<div><div>
          <div className="animated fadeIn">
           <div className="px-2 mb-1">
                <Link to={'/Components/BasicNotification'} style= {{ width:20 + '%' }} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">Add Notification</Link>

                  </div>

            <br /><div className="card" style={{ width: 57 + '%' }}>
              <div className="card-header">
                 Manage Notifications
              </div>
              <div className="card-block">


      <table  className="table table-hover table-outline mb-0 hidden-sm-down">

                <tbody>

                 {rows}</tbody>
            </table></div>


<br />

            </div>
          </div><div className="px-2 mb-1"><Link to={'/components/tabs'} style={{ width:20 + '%' }} className="px-1 nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">Filter Notifications</Link>
</div>
</div></div>




    )
  }
}

class TableRow extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    render()
    {
        return (<tr onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                    <td className="text-center">{this.props.data.title}<br />
                    {this.props.data.text}<br /></td></tr>

            );
    }
}


export default Notifications;
```

Comment: thanks. It worked a bit you can say 
Using this I can click a row but only the else condition is satisfied 
its only satisfying else condition not the earlier if else conditions
every time I click on any row its displaying the page corresponding to the else part

Comment: Can you tell what is being returned with `console.log(this.props.type.Bigtext)` also you can bind the handleClick function. I have updated the code

Comment: i wrote this as a breakpoint you can say to check 
console.log("abc"+this.state.data.type);
it had returned the output in console as "abc undefined"

Comment: That doesn't work because your state data is an array and hence should be
`console.log("abc"+this.state.data[0].type);` I have updated my code. Try that

Comment: It WORKED BRO ::)

Comment: Nice. Glad to have helped.

Comment: yup wish to have your any contact if needed help in future

Comment: You can always post a question on SO, I am highly active

Comment: do u have any knowledge regarding how to hit an api and all that

Comment: you can make use of either fetch, axios or jquery ajax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42694913/7645971

using fetch I'm gonna do but I don't know how to do Actually I don't know how to use POST request 
This is the link for that file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802331/how-to-send-input-data-taken-dynamically-to-the-server-using-post-request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828145/how-to-insert-a-dropdown-using-react-js