# Hitting an API in react on submit button (POST request in REACT JS)

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { Dropdown, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem, Progress } from 'reactstrap';

class Modals extends Component {
constructor(){
super();
  fetch("http://api-env.bt2qjip33m.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/beacons" ,
 {
  method: 'post',
 headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Authorization' : 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OGMyOTdiO  WQzZWM4NjY4MDMwNDBlNjgiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImtrQGxpdGlmZXIuY29tIiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiS2lzaGxheSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiS2lzaG9yZSIsImlhdCI6MTQ4OTE0NzgzM30.nHW5w3SSov8ySziblmw2VNlGI3CsZFR-v41Jeg9uBVs'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
name: "beacon name",
description: "beacon description here",
uuid: "mnvijefnv",
major: "2",
minor: "2",
manufacturer: "m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24",
beaconType: "type1",
location: "main gate1",
floor: "",
zone: "58c29c06d3ec866803040e6e"
})
}).then(function(response){
if(response.ok) {
  console.log(response)
return response;
}
throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
}).then(function(data) { 
console.log(data);
})
.catch(function(error) {
console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error);
});
  }

   render() {
   return (<div><div>
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <br /><div className="card" style={{ width: 57 + '%' }}>
          <div className="card-header">
             Beacon Settings
          </div>
          <div className="card-block">
            <div className="input-group mb-1">
              <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="icon-user"></i></span>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="UUID" />
            </div>

            <div className="input-group mb-1">
              <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Major Number"/>
            </div>

            <div className="input-group mb-1">
              <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Minor Number"/>
            </div>

            <div className="input-group mb-1">
              <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Manufacturer Number"/>
            </div><center>
            <Link to={'/components/tabs'} style={{ width: 27 + '%' }} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">Save</Link>

<Link to={'/components/tabs'} style={{ width: 27 + '%' }} className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-success" activeClassName="active">Advance Settings</Link>
</center>

        </div>
      </div>
 </div></div>
  </div>
  
    
  
     )
 }
}

export default Modals;
```

I want to save the data to the server using POST request 
It had taken data from the fields by the user.
The data will be sent to the  server on clicking on "Save" button.
Actually I searched for that but I didn't found any relevant information

Comment: You can use `fetch('url', {options}).then().catch()`. Take a look. You have an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694896/reactjs-put-data-from-api-by-id-through-react-router-to-details-view)

Comment: As I understand on the save button press you  want to POST the form and then navigate to another component. Am I correct. If yes, then where do you want to POST, i mean which is the api endpoint

Comment: _POST_ `/api/v1/beacons`
i think you are asking about that

Comment: server will be litifer.com/Beacons

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828145/how-to-insert-a-dropdown-using-react-js